# Angular npm install returning errors

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Running npm install return errors. It can be run successfully using npm install --force but I dont want to use --force. Reading the errors I understand there is version compatibility issue but not able to understand which line talks about the version in my package json and how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

[image]

tried running npm install with force but dont want to use force command

Comment: The error message shows that you need to upgrade the packages mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Angular CLI and Angular DevKit Packages:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

npm update @angular-devkit/core
```